# Stereo Matching - Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, matching, dynamic-programming

I am supposed to implement Dynamic programming algorithm for Stereo matching problem. I have read 2 research papers but still haven't understood as to how do I write my own c++ program for that !

Is there any book or resource that's available somewhere that I can use to get an idea as to how to start coding actually ?

Internet search only gives me journal and conference papers regarding Dynamic Programming but not how to implement the algorithm step by step.

Thanks

Varun

Comment: Perhaps you can start by explaining what Stereo matching is and what papers you are talking about?

Comment: Dynamic Programming is a *style* of problem-solving that you would apply (and can apply to any language, not just C++), it is not a single, specific algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this paper by Cox, Hingorany and Rao](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~djacobs/CMSC426/Slides/stereo_algo.pdf), old but still a classic.

Cost computation is pixel based, but the generalization to cross-correlation in a neigborhood is trivial, as is also its generalization to a pyramid scheme in which full match is done only at the lowest resolution, and the result used to refine at higher resolutions by doing the DP search only in a small band around the lower res match. This idea was the basis of [the better known paper by Luc van Gool and Marc Pollefeys](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~marc/pubs/KochJVCA00.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the challenge of implementing dynamic programming is that it is more of a problem-solving technique than it is a pure algorithm.

An effective resource that I used once to implement a DP solution is [Michael Trick's tutorial](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/dynamic/dynamic.html); it's not been kept up-to-date, but it's still a good place to start.  This tutorial's section on [common characteristics of DP problems](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/dynamic/node4.html#SECTION00040000000000000000) is still one of the best conceptual roadmaps I've found for DP.

I'd also check out the resources listed in the [Wikipedia dynamic programming article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dynamic programming tutorial (well lecture actually) in video form, might help: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-ten